# Cloudflare Railgun compression not efficient

Tags: http, compression, cloudflare

My page is returning the header:

```
cf-railgun:05a62694f6 0.49 0.011931 0031 e6be
```

I understand this to mean that the Railgun compression is reducing the requests from the origin server to Cloudflare by around 50%.

However, when inspecting my served HTML page, it is:

- ~20kb uncompressed (without Gzip)
- ~6kb compressed (with Gzip)

And most importantly, the **only** text that changes on each request is this line:

```
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="PGUHGdJZ60C6SD3FwgvrOpZcyiqSkc5RzCZBRvjX9CUjUGUtYgwDiM4Wq0UF5q6w6CPmwx5YgRx4lzPRnDiyMmtPngA="/>
```

About 1/4 of the way down the page.  I would of thought that if Railgun was only sending changes, then I should be achieving a far far better compression rate.

Is something wrong here, or is a tag like this changing on each page exposing a weakness in Railgun's compression algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, looks like I misunderstood the percentage.  0.49 means the data was 0.49% of the original, so very tiny indeed!